# Drag and Drop not working from Outlook to Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I am using the drop event to get the file(pdf) that is dragged and dropped from outlook and `event.dataTransfer.items.length` returns "0". Also, `event.dataTransfer.files` also returns an empty array.

`event.dataTransfer.files[0]`, also returns undefined..

Works in all browsers except Firefox.

My Firefox version is 105.03.

Comment: It seems like Firefox blocks dropping files from Outlook into the browser. I can't drop PDFs or JPEGs.

Comment: @the_man Try again, it should work now as per the latest answer. Consider accepting it if so.

Answer (score 2):

With [Firefox Nightly 113.0a1](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/113.0a1/releasenotes/) this feature was added:

> A 13-year-old feature request was fulfilled, and Firefox now supports files being drag-and-dropped directly from Microsoft Outlook. A special thanks to volunteer contributor Marco Spiess for helping to get this across the finish line!

The closed bug report for reference: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=580928

Answer (score 1):

I am also having this issue. From what I have found, it is not that Firefox block drag and drops. It is just that they do not support it.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=580928